# How to iterate over a Tensor in Tensorflow and change its values if necessary?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Assume I have a Tensor in TensorFlow of shape [600, 11]. All the elements of the last (11th) column are zero. I want to iterate over the values of the Tensor like that: For each row, I check whether the maximum of the first 10 elements of the row is greater than a value X. If True, then keep the row unchanged, if False, then set the first 10 elements of the row to be equal to zero and make the 11th element equal to 1. How can I do that? The structure of my Tensor is shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.zeros([600, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.random.uniform([600,10], minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32)
c = tf.concat([b, a], axis=1)
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. For more information, [please see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate through tensors, nor set the value of individual elements. Tensors are immutable, so you always have to build a new tensor from the previous one instead. This is how you can do something like what you describe:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def modify_matrix(matrix, X):
    all_but_last_column = matrix[:, :-1]
    max_per_row = tf.reduce_max(all_but_last_column, axis=1)
    replace = tf.concat([tf.zeros_like(all_but_last_column),
                         tf.ones_like(matrix[:, -1])[:, tf.newaxis]], axis=1)
    mask = max_per_row > X
    return tf.where(mask, matrix, replace)

nums = [list(range(i * 10, (i + 1) * 10)) + [0] for i in range(1, 5)]
print(*nums, sep='\n')
# [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 0]
# [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 0]
# [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 0]
# [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 0]
matrix = tf.constant(nums)
X = tf.constant(36, dtype=matrix.dtype)
result = modify_matrix(matrix, X)
print(sess.run(result))
# [[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1]
#  [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1]
#  [30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39  0]
#  [40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49  0]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. This seems that it works! I also found another solution as shown below!

Answer (score 0):

I also found another solution that it worked for me:

```
import tensorflow as tf

zeroes = tf.zeros([600, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
ones = tf.ones([600, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.random.uniform([600,10], minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32)
threshold = tf.constant(0.6, dtype=tf.float32)

check = tf.reduce_max(tf.cast(b > threshold, dtype=tf.float32), axis=1)
last_col = tf.where(check>0, zeroes, ones)
new_b = tf.where(check>0, b, tf.zeros([600, 10], dtype=tf.float32))
new_matrix = tf.concat([new_b, last_col], axis=1)
```